# Let $A$ be a 3 x 2 matrix. Is it possible for $Ax= b $ to have a unique solution for some $b \neq 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra

If yes, prove $Ax = b$. If not, explain why?
I know that A represents a mapping from  $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^3$. It could be 1-1 since $$\dim(\mathbb R^2) \le \dim(\mathbb R^3)$$ If indeed it is 1-1, then I can answer the question asked but how do I go about verifying it. Thank you.

Comment: Actually $\dim(R^2)<\dim(R^3)$ (strictly less, not less or equal).

Comment: Technically strictly less implies less or equal...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that by the rank-nullity theorem the dimension of the image of $A$ is less or equal $2$ so there are two cases:

- if $rank A=2$ then if $b\in Im A$ then there is a unique solution for the equation and obviously there isn't a solution if $b\not\in Im A$.
- if $rank A<2$ then $\dim\ker A>0$ and so if $x$ is a solution then $x+u$ is also a solution for every $u\in\ker A$ and then there are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: The way I've been taught is that the rank of a matrix is simply the dimension of the image it maps, which in this it would be 3. It this way of thinking not correct?

Comment: @curiousmind1995: It is the dimension of the image, but I think you're confusing the image with the codomain.  If $A$ is $3 \times 2$ then as a map the image of $A$ is a **subspace** of $\mathbb R^3$, it doesn't have to be all of $\mathbb R^3$ (in fact, it can't be!).  For example if all the entries of $A$ are zero then the image will be the zero subspace which has dimension $0$.

Comment: Yup, I learned that in discrete but I forgot about it. Thanks a lot!